# SQL - print names with letter starting in 's' or ending in 's'. Exclude Males

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm writing an SQL command to display pet names that start or end with the letter 's' and exclude all males from the output list.

I have no idea how to exclude males from the list. I have a column called Gender which hols the gender of the pet. This is either M = Male, F = Female and X = other.

My understanding is that s% is checking for s at the start of a name and %s is checking for an s at the end of the name. Below is my command so far.

```
SELECT pet_id, Name, Type, Breed, Gender
FROM pet
WHERE Name LIKE 's%' OR Name LIKE '%s'
```

Comment: Despite the obvious `ms-access` tag, deleting the *"im using ms access if that helps"* was probably unwise in the edit as that's the major give away. see my answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `like` operator with the asterisk (*) in Access. the `*` wildcard represents any number of characters in a string.

```
SELECT pet_id, Name, Type, Breed, Gender
FROM pet
WHERE (Name LIKE "s*" OR Name LIKE "*s")
and gender <> "M"
```

> MS Access uses the asterisk (*) wildcard character instead of the percent sign (%) wildcard character.

Comment: Worked great Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT pet_id, Name, Type, Breed, Gender
FROM pet
WHERE (Name LIKE 's%' OR Name LIKE '%s')
and gender <> 'M'
```

Comment: The SQL command works but it only creates the table. There is no data in the table. There should be a female cat called tiddles and a snake called slippy. Any idea why there not appearing?

Comment: What you write makes no sense. Please clarify. Your table is empty and you want to fill it first with data?

Comment: Yeah. So the SQL command passes and shows a table with the headings pet_id, Name, Type, Breed and Gender. But there is no data below these titles when there should be the following data: P0001, Tiddles, cat, persian, F

Comment: Well then INSERT the data. If the table is empty you need to put something in there first. Use the `insert` statement for that.